# how to make a textField moves

Tags: iphone, objective-c

when I press on it I can change position freely in View

-(IBAction) add :(id)sender {

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(kLeftMargin, 8.0, kTextFieldWidth, kTextFieldHeight);

UITextField * textfieldToAdd = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];






        textfieldToAdd.borderStyle =  UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect; 
        textfieldToAdd.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        textfieldToAdd.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
        textfieldToAdd.placeholder = @"";
        textfieldToAdd.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        textfieldToAdd.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo ; // no auto correction support

        textfieldToAdd.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;   // use the default type input method (entire keyboard)
        textfieldToAdd.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

        textfieldToAdd.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;  // has a clear 'x' button to the right

        textfieldToAdd.tag = kViewTag;     // tag this control so we can remove it later for recycled cells

        textfieldToAdd.delegate = self;    // let us be the delegate so we know when the keyboard's "Done" button is pressed

        // Add an accessibility label that describes what the text field is for.
        [textfieldToAdd setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"textfieldToAdd", @"")];



[self.view addSubview:textfieldToAdd];
```

}

Comment: Could you expand on your question and explain it in detail with an example. Also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/38794459@N06/5556005854/

Comment: You want dragging the textfield ?

Comment: Yes i want dragging the textField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the gestureRecognizer to your ViewDidLoad and then create the function
or better look here [MoveME example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html)

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panPiece:)];
[panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
[panGesture setDelegate:self];
[self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

- (void)panPiece:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer     state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
        textfieldToAdd.center = CGPointMake([self center].x + translation.x, [self center].y + translation.y);
        [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[self superview]];
    }
}
```

Comment: @PasstissiPhone not without a discription

Comment: @Seega request for member center in something not a structure or union

Comment: @PasstissiPhone `textFieldToAdd.center`  
common you want to move your textfield then, this little mistake you should solve yourself

Comment: @PasstissiPhone no one will help you, if you don't explain your problems

Answer (score 0):

i want dragging this textField

- (void)viewDidLoad {

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)] autorelease];

}

-(IBAction) add :(id)sender {

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(kLeftMargin, 8.0, kTextFieldWidth, kTextFieldHeight);

UITextField * textfieldToAdd = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];






        textfieldToAdd.borderStyle =  UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect; 
        textfieldToAdd.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        textfieldToAdd.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
        textfieldToAdd.placeholder = @"";
        textfieldToAdd.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        textfieldToAdd.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo ; // no auto correction support

        textfieldToAdd.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;   // use the default type input method (entire keyboard)
        textfieldToAdd.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

        textfieldToAdd.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;  // has a clear 'x' button to the right

        textfieldToAdd.tag = kViewTag;     // tag this control so we can remove it later for recycled cells
        textfieldToAdd.delegate = self;    // let us be the delegate so we know when the keyboard's "Done" button is pressed

        // Add an accessibility label that describes what the text field is for.
        [textfieldToAdd setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"textfieldToAdd", @"")];





[self.view addSubview:textfieldToAdd];
```

}

Comment: yes but whats the problem with my code? what happens and doen't happen?